# Vietnam passport with green card, do I need a transit visa for my connecting flight in Japan?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, japan, vietnamese-citizens

Looking to book an alternative flight that will require two one ways with a 3 hour "stopover" at the  NRT airport before the connecting flight. Since I will need to check in my bags and pick it up at baggage claim, will I need to get a visa in NRT? I assume this will require me to go through customs since I am in a sense "leaving the airport".

Can I avoid going through customs if I forgo check-in bags? The flight would require a transfer from T1 to T2 and would then not require a visa?

Trying to figure somethings out here.

Thanks!

Comment: Which airline(s) are the flights with?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it seems these are separate bookings.

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a passport and a
>   confirmed onward ticket to a third country within 72 hours can
>   obtain a Shore Pass on arrival **if there are no connecting
>   flights on the same calendar day**

For logical reasons, I suspect this information is incomplete and that your scenario would qualify for this visa exemption. Nevertheless, based on the above you're not getting on the flight to NRT without a visa with separate bookings (even if not checking a bag, the problem is you won't be considered a transit passenger).

So yes, you'll need a transit visa with separate bookings. If it's a single booking, then any bags will be checked through, and you won't need a visa.

Comment: Depends on the airlines.  If they are the same airline, or an alliance, then it's possible the bags will be checked through

Comment: @Doc Still, most handling agents would consider the transit point to be the final destination, luggage or not. Been told this very clearly by most of the ones I've asked.